# How to add number and percentage to pie chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to number and percentage to the categories, this is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)
library(scales)

figvad <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/vadev.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)

library(repr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(repr.plot.width=17, repr.plot.height=10)

ggplot(figvadf, aes(x=Type, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 0.5) +
  coord_polar()+
theme_minimal()+
 theme(text = element_text(size=14, face=4),plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,3), "lines"))+
xlab("Types of Vaccines")+
ylab("")
```

I tried, but I wasn't successful:

```
geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(factor(Type  / sum(factor(Type) * 100, 1), "%"))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

figvad <- read.csv(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq",
                           "/learning/main/vadev.txt"), sep = '\t')

ggplot(melt(table(figvad$Type)) %>% mutate(perc = value/sum(value)),
       aes(1, value, fill=Var1)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack", color = "gray20", alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_text(aes(1.6, label = paste0(Var1, "\n", value, " (", 
                                    scales::percent(perc), ")")),
             hjust = "outward",
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn", name = "Type") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", clip = "off") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

```r
ggplot(melt(table(figvad$Type)) %>% 
         mutate(perc = value/sum(value)) %>%
         mutate(label = paste0(Var1, "\n", value, " (", 
                               scales::percent(perc), ")")),
       aes(label, value, fill = label)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack", color = "gray20", alpha = 0.8, width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn", name = "Type") +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", clip = "off") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14, face = 4),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 3), "lines"),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Types of Vaccines") +
  ylab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @AllanCameron, actually I want to apply it to my updated code, I just updated my question, I'm also trying to remove the legend if the graph itself is enough to navigate the info. Please check out my code. I appreciate the support. Sorry I was working on my code before you post your answer. I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much @AllanCameron, is it possible that I use the graph I generated, I updated the question with an image.

Comment: @user432797 sorry, you asked for a pie chart in the title of your question. The plot you showed is not a pie chart.

Comment: I thought it is called a piechart @AllanCameron, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @user432797 see my update. I don't think this works quite so well, but if you prefer it, this is how it's done.

Comment: Awesome @AllanCameron, it worked, fantastic, what should I call this type of chart?

Comment: @user432797 I guess I'd call it a radial bar chart